# Making chatbot that can giving response base on time

Tags: aiml, program-o

I'm using program-o to develop my chatbot on my own website
Let's say if I type "good morning" to my bot at night, the bot will still respond to me "morning".
what I want is if I type "good morning" to my bot at night, the bot will respond "current time is 9pm, so you shouldn't use `morning`  ".
Is there any possible solution to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to look at the <date> tag and check its contents. I answered this question here:

[AIML Chatbot response differs at different times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717225/aiml-chatbot-response-differs-at-different-times)

By coincidence, I also posted a category that handles "Good morning".